# Ansible multiple host transfer

Tags: ansible

I have a script which runs and gives o/p as a.txt b.txt upto 30 odd files.The copy is executed only if the destination remote file has been modified. is there a simple way to do this. All my host are defined in a single group.

I do not want to transfer all 30 files, only the file which corresponds to the destination.

Answer (score 0):

The [synchronize](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/synchronize_module.html) module is your friend. Have a look at the examples, something like

```
- name: Synchronization using rsync protocol (pull)
  synchronize:
    mode: pull
    src: rsync://somehost.com/path/
    dest: /some/absolute/path/
```

should do the trick.